# Unable to access S3 bucket used by CloudTrail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have an Amazon S3 bucket that is being used by CloudTrail.

However, the S3 bucket is not visible in S3.

When I click on the bucket in CloudTrail, it links to S3 but I get `access denied`.

The bucket is currently in use by CloudTrail, and based on the icons that seems to be working fine.

So, it seems this is an existing bucket but I cannot access it!

I also tried to access the S3 bucket with the root account, but the same issue occurs there.

Please advise on how I would regain access.

Comment: do you have admin access of the aws account ?

Comment: I wonder if it is pointing to a bucket in a different AWS Account?

Comment: are you part of a multi aws account set up?Cloud trail may be set to a bucket belonging to another account.

Answer (score 0):

Just because cloudtrail has access to the bucket, doesn't mean your account also does.

You would need to talk to whoever manages your security and request access. or if this is your account, make sure you are logged in with credentials that have the proper access.

Comment: Yes its my account. im logged in with the correct credentials even on the root account im getting the same issue...

Comment: If that is truly the case, that is bizarre - and probably worthy of an inquiry to AWS tech support. Root accounts should have access to 100% of the resources in your account at all times.